# Disk File Transfer in twain dll when scanning multiple images together

Tags: c#, twain

I want scan many images toghether in c# code, I use twain 3.0.0.
I want to change transfer mode in twain to save my images directly and don't collect these in RAM.

btnstart:

```
    TwainSession _twain;
    if (_twain.State == 4)
            {
                _stopScan = false;
                if (_twain.CurrentSource.Capabilities.CapUIControllable.IsSupported)
                {
                    // hide scanner ui if possible
                    if (_twain.CurrentSource.Enable(SourceEnableMode.NoUI, false, this.Handle) == ReturnCode.Success)
                    {
                        btnStopScan.Enabled = true;
                        btnStartCapture.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
    }
```

data transfer:

```
     _twain.DataTransferred += (s, e) =>
            {
                PlatformInfo.Current.Log.Info("Transferred data event on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                // example on getting ext image info
                var infos = e.GetExtImageInfo(NTwain.Data.ExtendedImageInfo.Camera).Where(it => it.ReturnCode == ReturnCode.Success);
                foreach (var it in infos)
                {
                    var values = it.ReadValues();
                    PlatformInfo.Current.Log.Info(string.Format("{0} = {1}", it.InfoID, values.FirstOrDefault()));
                    break;
                }

                Image img = null;

                if (e.NativeData != IntPtr.Zero)
                {

                    var stream = e.GetNativeImageStream();
                   if (stream != null)
                    {
                        img = Image.FromStream(stream);

                   }
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FileDataPath))
                {
                    img = new Bitmap(e.FileDataPath);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what the question you're having is exactly? Isn't the eventhandler triggered? Does it work but still exhaust memory?

Comment: @ChristiaanNieuwlaat This code works, but causes RAM to fill up, I exactly want to change transfer mode in twain session.(Change native transfer mode to Disk file transfer mode)

Comment: In the documentation on the LeadTools website there is a section about setting the transferoptions of the twain session. Maybe this could help you :-) https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/tw/twainsession-transferoptions.html . If you want I could create a snippet as answer here :-)